# Write to ctypes stdin python

Tags: python, stdin, ctypes

I have the following python code

```
import ctypes
import sys
dll = ctypes.CDLL('./file.so')
if __name__ == "__main__":
    dll.myFunction()
```

The function myFunction waits for a stdin input, so my question is: how can I simulate this input using python?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user

Comment: A solution you'll find in many variations is to temporarily replace the current stdin with a pipe. Start by saving a copy of the current stdin, e.g. `old_stdin = os.dup(sys.stdin.fileno())`. Then create a pipe, e.g. `fd_read, fd_write = os.pipe()`, and set the read end as the new stdin, e.g. `os.dup2(fd_read, sys.stdin.fileno())`. Before calling `myFunction`, write to `fd_write` via `os.write`.  After calling the function, restore the original stdin using  `os.dup2(old_stdin, sys.stdin.fileno())` and close `old_stdin` and the pipe file descriptors via `os.close`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could use xautomation http://xautomation.sourceforge.net/keyboard.html

Comment: It would probably be better to answer specifically by showing how that link would help. And writing some code.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be required for app automation tasks so I could recommend [PyUserInput](https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput) package for input simulation:

```py
from pykeyboard import PyKeyboard

kbd = PyKeyboard()
kbd.tap_key('h')
kbd.tap_key('i')
```

Example for windows users (althogh [PyUserInput](https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput) is corssplatform for Windows it is built atop [pywin32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/)):

```py
import time
import win32com.client as comclt
wsh = comclt.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
wsh.Run("calc")
time.sleep(1)
wsh.AppActivate("Calculator")

from pykeyboard import PyKeyboard 
kbd = PyKeyboard()
kbd.type_string(["1"]+["0"]*6,interval=1)
```